# Linking component to separate element, and displaying it relative to that element

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

So i'm in  need of creating list popout that can be attached to a trigger element showing the list below that element.

Consider the following design:
[image]

When the plus icon is clicked the list of links appears relative to it.

I figured the list could be easily acomplished with a simple component where you feed it an array of link descriptors and it renders a list, something like this:

```
export interface LinkDescriptor {
  name: string,
  destination?: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation-popout',
  template: `
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        <a [attr.href]="item.destination">{{item.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>`,
  styleUrls: ['./navigation-popout.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationPopoutComponent {
  @Input()
  items: LinkDescriptor[];
}
```

Now that gets me the list of links, i could style them to look as the design.

The bit im struggling with is how to link the trigger, in this case a button elsewhere in the document, and the popout component. The other issue is how to manage the styling.

I know in order to absolutally position the popout relative to the trigger they both need to be within a relative or absolutally positions parent. However having to remember to do that every time this is used adds maintanence overhead.

I have considered some form of directive that i could decorate the trigger button with and it will dynamically insert the popup below the trigger item, however im not too keen on that idea as it means directly manipulating the DOM outside the scope of the trigger element, IE wrapping it.

The other option i considered was using `ng-content` and providing the trigger element within the declaration of the nav popout.

So something like this:

```html
<app-navigation-popout>
    <button>+</button>
</app-navigation-popout>
```

However i'm not too keen on that idea either.

Just wondering how others would tackle this problem of relating the two elements together and position one component relative to the other element it is linked to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So i decided on a solution and thought i would share in case others found it usefull.

So i split it down into two compoenents, one that displays a list of links:

```
export interface LinkDescriptor {
  name: string,
  destination?: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-links-list',
  template: `
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        <a [attr.href]="item.destination">{{item.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>`,
  styleUrls: ['./links-list.component.scss']
})
export class LinksList{
  @Input()
  items: LinkDescriptor[];
}
```

I then created a second component whose job it is to wrap the trigger and the links list. This second component deals with displaying and hiding the links and positioning them.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-links-list-popout',
  template: `
  <span class="container">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <app-links-list [items]="items" *ngIf="showList"></app-links-list>
  </span>`,
  styleUrls: ['./links-list-popout.component.scss']
})
export class LinksListPopout {
  @Input()
  items: LinkDescriptor[];

  showList: boolean;

  toggle() {
    this.showList = !this.showList;
  }
}
```

Now when i want to implement a list of links i can do so like this:

```html
<div>
  <app-naivgation-list-popout [items]="[{name: 'link', destination: '/place'}]" #linksPopout>
    <button (click)="linksPopout.toggle()">+</button>
  </app-naivgation-list-popout>
</div>
```